# How to deal with users asking the same question several times?

Tags: discussion, flags

A person asks the same question multiple times. Many users reply with the right solution, but he does not understand it. The OP then modifies the question and asks it again.

How can I deal with that type of user? I used a downvoted, but I think I should flag it? What flag would be best for this situation?

Comment: close as a duplicate is what I normally do and leave a comment....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If they are variations of the exact same question, close it as a duplicate of the original question. And if the OP insists it's a different question, ask them to clarify what the exact difference is and how the previous question did not address his concerns.

Other than that any voting is up to you.

Comment: thanks..for your reply. you are right...

Comment: +1: If the user really believes that it is a different question, it is important to not assume that he is wrong without trying to understand his point.

Comment: If it is more or less exact the same question what about flagging for moderator attention and request immediate deletion. Is there any value in having nearly identical questions around? It would probably depend how similar they are?

Comment: It highly depends on the situation @Trilarion. Unless it's a pure spammer account deletion would be the very last step.

Comment: This is, I believe, one of the best use cases for [Mjölnir](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212).