# What's the correct action to take once I've answered a user's repeated question?

Tags: support, flags

I realize there is already a general consensus on the [correct action for a repost of a recent question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255095/3773066),  that is to [close it as a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286335/3773066) of the first. In the Duplicate flag, it states:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

The latter clause being exempt for same-user duplicates. This is where my question differs to others.

I spent the past few days answering and critiquing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30981815/3773066) based on the author's additional criteria with each edit. Then, today while searching deeper into Unanswered questions, I found [this identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30549167/3773066) by the same user with no answers but a couple of valid suggestions in comments. **What action should be taken here?**

Is there a way to merge the two questions so that no comments and answers are lost? I'd hate to have lost the efforts I put into researching the answer (though what I personally learned I will retain), but it *is* the newer question and therefore the duplicate. Or will one of the questions still be deleted/closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark the old one (with no answers) as a duplicate of the new one (with your answer).  Make the canonical question the **best** one, not the oldest one.

Comment: And downvote the one you close, as reposting is bad.